# Discord.js - ReferenceError: member is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, roles

I am having issues with this, i am trying to add a role called Simon Says Player, can anyone help??

```
bot.on('message', message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'join':

            let person = message.guild.member

            if (!person) {
                return message.reply('Couldn`t find the user!');
            }

            let mainRole = (role => role.name === "Simon Says Player");

            member.addRole(mainRole.id);

            message.channel.send('Successfully Entered The Game!!')

            break;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`member` is in fact `undefined`, you did not state the intended function but from what I can see you're trying to give a role to the member that sent the `join` command.

```js
bot.on('message', message => {

  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

  switch (args[0]) {
    case 'join':

      let person = message.guild.member

      if (!person) {
        return message.reply('Couldn`t find the user!');
      }

      let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Simon Says Player");

      message.member.roles.add(mainRole.id);

      message.channel.send('Successfully Entered The Game!!')

      break;
  }
})
```

Comment: so how do i fix this? Im new to programming

Comment: copy and paste my answer, I already wrote what you need to do.

Comment: I just edited my comment based on your comment to the other answer, you're using discord.js v12 so you need to use `roles.add()` instead of `addRole()`

Comment: (node:17088) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not an Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes. It is a role tho

Comment: You didn't define `mainRole` correctly, I fixed it for you

Comment: You're welcome and welcome to SO, if an answer solves your question, accept it to let others know what worked and that the question has been answered

Comment: if you dont mind, what button is that. there is a few on this page aha

Comment: the tick mark next to the answer, under the voting arrows

Answer (score 0):

Try `message.member.addRole(mainRole.id)` instead of `member.addRole(mainRole.id)`

This should work in your example :

```
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'join':

                let person = message.member

                if (!person) {
                    return message.reply('Couldn`t find the user!');
                }

                let mainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Simon Says Player");
                message.member.roles.add(mainRole);


                message.channel.send('Successfully Entered The Game!!')

            break;
    }
```

Comment: Also, you defined `person` as `message.guild.member` which is wrong: use `message.member` instead. You can find the docs for `Message` [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message)

Comment: TypeError: message.member.addRole is not a function